# How to evaluate a date difference in years, months and days (ruby)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to make a simple difference between two dates:

```
Date.parse("2009-06-20") - Date.today
```

This gives me the difference of the dates in days.

Anyone know a way to easily convert that to the following format:

```
The event occurred X years, Y months and Z days ago
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [More precise distance_of_time_in_words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224613/more-precise-distance-of-time-in-words)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer here:

[More precise distance_of_time_in_words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224613/more-precise-distance-of-time-in-words)

with this gem:

https://github.com/radar/dotiw

Comment: I am trying to use this gem but its not requiring or loading in rails or even in ruby.
I tried using require 'dotiw' , require 'dotiw/lib' require 'lib/dotiw' but nothing worked. can you help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for [distance_of_times_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M002261)

Comment: Good answer, but that's Ruby-on-Rails specific. The poster will have to extract that code in a pure ruby program. (He didn't mention Rails, so I presume it's a non-rails specific question.)

Comment: My bad, I'm using ruby-on-rails

Comment: That's good, but I need something more precise. Do you know any other way?

Comment: I guess it's pretty useful for most cases. The gem you found seems interesting, gonna check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a RubyGem which returns Time difference  in a hash like {:year => 0, :month => 0,...}

The link is : https://rubygems.org/gems/time_diff

Comment: Your gem seems good, but I think you should get working on it. You should add some text and formatting to it. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thank you. Sure I will improve my gem.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for difference in days, hours, seconds.  Add the fields that you need.

```
def calculate_difference
  minutes = (Date.parse("2009-06-20") - Date.today).to_i / 60
  days = minutes / (24*60)
  minutes -= days * 24*60
  hours = minutes / 60
  minutes -= hours * 60
  "#{days}d#{hours}h#{minutes}m"
end
```

Comment: The problem begins exactly with moths, because there are month with 28, 30 and 31 days..

Comment: I don't see how this can possibly work, since the to_i call rounds to days and throws away any extra hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I find these generic date differences useful in many cases:

```
time_a = Time.zone.parse('2020-05-30')
time_b = Time.zone.parse('2010-01-18')

time_diff = {
  years: time_a.year - time_b.year,
  months: time_a.month - time_b.month,
  days: time_a.day - time_b.day,
}
=> {:years=>10, :months=>4, :days=>12}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard, correct way to do this. As odd as it may seem the standard Ruby library has a Date class but no DateSpan functionality. Rails has a solution but it feels somewhat of a pain for me to require this whole mammoth for such a trivial task.